# What else should I try to get rid of HDD clicking?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

I turned off services: Windows Update, Superfetch. [File history](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoCcPjjmZqc) is turned off. Turned off [auto update](http://cdn.techgyd.com/Fig-2-Turn-off-Windows-Update-in-Windows-10.png), as much [background applications](https://www.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Turn-off-Background-apps-Windows-10.png) as possible. tried to use without antivirus. Drivers from laptop manufacturer are installed. Windows is updated. And sometime HDD load is very high - 50-100% without obvious reason - even in idle. What else should I try ?
Under Linux nothing is clicking (dual boot).

Comment: Some troubleshooting: 1) Make sure it's the HDD that is clicking. Open the box (take proper care and precautions). It could possibly be the video-card's fan. 2) Try the command: >`chkdsk /f c:`  with an elevated level on the Windows Command Processor.

Comment: @ejbytes I tried to check disk - no problems and system integrity is also alright.

Comment: 100% sure it's not the video-card fan? It might sound like the HDD.

Comment: http://harddriveclicking.net/ Did some looking. Seems these people might agree on my first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: @ejbytes it's not because under Linux there is no clicking, I think impossible create fan clicking programmatically, but HDD - there is actuator arm, HDD probably in cycle of switching on/off or something else.

Comment: Linux is an OS. I don't understand your comment. I know how a hard drive operates. The thing I don't know is YOUR experience. So, the troubleshooting list. Check out the link I provided. Good luck.

Comment: @ejbytes thanks for the link, I will see. While I'm using Linux there is no clicking sound. It appears under Windows.

Comment: Your comment seems to imply, to me, that you are using a dual boot or something similar? The HDD in Linux, no click. The HDD in Windows, clicking. Same PC. Dual boot? Explain please.

Comment: @ejbytes Yes, dual boot.

Comment: Ah. I've used dual boot before. Then ultimately converted an unused laptop to dedicated Linux machine. Was your machine bought as a Windows machine, and then you installed the dual boot?

Comment: There is a reason for my line of questioning.

Comment: @ejbytes It had Ubuntu preinstalled, then I installed another distro and Windows. But my model mostly on a market with Windows.

Comment: I would consider this. Backup all your data (files, pics, whatever is important) now. Reinstall Windows (I hope you have a disc). Most people don't have a Windows disc, which is a shame for the owners. Let me know if you do before I ramble on. There could be a potential problem with dual boot systems. Linux, when installs, usually asks for the Owner to accept that the Linux OS be installed on the inner partition, thus moving the Window partition. See the potential problem now?

Comment: @ejbytes Actually I never seen such question from Linux installers. Yes, I see now.

Comment: @ejbytes But people on internet usually talking that there either no difference or outer partitions even faster on modern hard drives (https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1419336.html).

Comment: @ejbytes And it seems that people start having such problem after upgrade to WIn10.

Comment: @AndyD Have you looked at Task Manager -> Resource Monitor -> Disk tab to see which processes are responsible for the disk I/O? (I am amazed that 16 comments have gone by without this suggestion!)

Comment: @Jamie Hanrahan process can be any, nothing certain. BUT I thinks I found solution, I'll check this out and will tell the result. [Here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2936631/hard-disk-clicking-read-action.html) is talking about Intel Rapid Storage Technologie which should be uninstalled, also Crystaldiskinfo may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**CrystalDiskInfo** utility solved my problem. **APM** should be set for Performance - FEh. [Here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2936631/hard-disk-clicking-read-action.html) is description by Apamedvapen on how to do it. Also for some users uninstall of **Intel Rapid Storage Technologie** can help (also at the link above).